# Office 365 API unable to access files via REST - Invalid audience Uri

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, outlook, office365

I have successfully gained access to Office365 mail, calendar and contacts via the API, but I am now trying to access the files and having no joy.

Here's what I have for accessing the mail...

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me

With the following Headers

Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXA.........nqWbv5EmA

That successfully returns something like this:

```
{
@odata.context: "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me"
@odata.id: "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('User.T@acklamgrange.org.uk')"
Id: "me@domainhere.org"
DisplayName: "Mr. User"
Alias: "User"
MailboxGuid: "76f56f59-5f30-46bd-9e22-afa0f53f1765"
}
```

And here's what I am trying for accessing files...

https://mydomainbithere-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/files/root

Then using the same Headers.

This returns:

```
Invalid audience Uri 'https://outlook.office365.com/'.
```

Do I need a different access key for files or could it be a permissions issue?

I've looked through all the documentation I can find but it's not all that clear how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tom, let's see if we can get you closer to joy.

Your access token does not target the -my.sharepoint.com resource. It targets outlook.office365.com. Take that bearer token and base64 decode the second part of the token (parts are separated by a period). You should be able to see which resources the token targets. See [Client Credentials Flow for Mail API in Python](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/02/10/client-credentials-flow-for-mail-api-in-python.aspx) for a break down of the token.

Have you enabled access to the Files resource in your app registration? Which platform are you using? There's probably a sample that can help you out here.

Comment: Hi @Michael Mainer... I've Base64 Decoded the token and I'm guessing this is the part you're referring to.

"scp":"Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.Read Contacts.ReadWrite full_access_as_user Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send"

Comment: Given that there's no reference to files, I am assuming I need to grant access to it elsewhere. I'm not entirely sure where though. I've logged in to Azure Portal but can't see there where it can be added.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Tom, the instructions found [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-iOS-Snippets#register-your-app-with-microsoft-azure) will get you the permissions set.

Comment: Hi Michael. OK, so I've granted access to files, but from what I can see, I need two different access tokens to files and outlook. Is this correct, or is there a way I've missed which allows for a single access token?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you'll need two access tokens for now. This scenario should go away once the unified API gets out of preview. The unified API will be the single endpoint for all of the services.